# How to clean the indexes, and ideally not create an additional array

Tags: python, array, numpy

So I answered [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424959/csv-file-containing-solutions-of-polynomial-equation) and probably did someone's homework along the way.
In the original question the OP has the `answer` variable and wants it split to real and imaginary values with the original coefficient (`q` in the original post) as an array for each q from 1 to 10, so you get an array of arrays looking like:

```
[[1,-0.39002422, 1.84237253, -0.39002422, -1.84237253, -0.10997578, 0.51949688,-0.10997578, -0.51949688j], 
[2, ...]
...
[10, ...]]
```

There are two things I'm unsatisfied with in the answer I gave that are the reason I'm asking for a CR.

1. The indexing: Isn't particularly readable, and I don't know how to make it more readable. For example `[q-1, 2*_+1]`. Would it have been better to create a variable `j = q-1` because `q-1` sees frequent use? Isn't that just moving the ugly to a different place?
2. The idea for the solution itself. The way I see it the original problem can be solved by splitting the answer array to a new array, but that feels somehow wrong. I can see several ways to create the new array, but I don't see a way to do it without creating the new array. Am I wrong and this is an OK solution or not, and why?

Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
export = np.empty([10,9])
for q in range(1,11):
    a0=1
    a1=3*q^2
    a2=4*q 
    a3=np.sqrt(q) 
    a4=q
    coeff=[a0, a1, a2, a3, a4]
    answer = np.roots(coeff)
    export[q-1, 0] = q
    for _ in range(len(answer)):
        export[q-1, 2*_+1] = answer[_].real
        export[q-1, 2*(_+1)] = answer[_].imag
with open("/tmp/latest_foo.csv", "ab") as output_file:
    np.savetxt(output_file, export, delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a review of the solution.

- `^` is xor in Python. It is not for computation of exponentials.
- When running code outside a method / class, it is a good practice to put the code inside a *main guard*. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) for more explanation.

  ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      ...
  ```

  When you are providing quick answers on a forum, the guard might not always be necessary. However, if you are writing reusable code for yourself, it is better to adopt the practice.
- By convention, `_` is used to represent a don't-care variable, which won't be used after its value is assigned, e.g. `v = [[] for _ in range(4)]`. It is undesirable to refer to it in an expression like `answer[_]`.
- The output is a pure text file. It is unnecessary to open it in binary mode (`b`). The original question does not suggest an append mode (`a`) either.
- The `q-1` index would no longer work if `q` is changed to a different group of values. Therefore, it is better to use `enumerate` in this case:

  ```
  for i, q in enumerate(RANGE_Q):
     ...
     export[i, 0] = q
     ...
  ```

  A better approach is to use `zip`:

  ```
  for q, output_row in zip(RANGE_Q, output_arr):
      ...
      output_row[0] = q
      ...
  ```
- The assignments to the output numpy array can be improved, as shown in my solution below.

Here is my solution.

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define constants
    RANGE_Q = range(1, 11)               # Range of q values
    POLY_DEG = 4                         # Degree of polynomial
    OUTPUT_PATH = "/tmp/latest_foo.csv"  # Output csv path

    # Compute roots
    roots_arr = np.array([np.roots([1, 3*q*q, 4*q, np.sqrt(q), q]) for q in RANGE_Q])
    
    # Construct output array and assign values
    output_arr = np.empty(shape=(len(RANGE_Q), POLY_DEG * 2 + 1))
    output_arr[:, 0] = RANGE_Q
    output_arr[:, 1::2] = roots_arr.real
    output_arr[:, 2::2] = roots_arr.imag

    # Save results to output file
    np.savetxt(OUTPUT_PATH, output_arr, fmt="%.4g", delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic method for that last `for` loop would be to use nested list comprehensions.  It's likely faster, as well:

```
[item for sublist in [[x.real, x.imag] for x in answer] for item in sublist]
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) for details about what's happening here, if you're not already familiar with list comprehensions.

In other words, instead of these four lines:

```
export[q-1, 0] = q
for _ in range(len(answer)):
      export[q-1, 2*_+1] = answer[_].real
      export[q-1, 2*(_+1)] = answer[_].imag
```

You could write this:

```
line = [q]
line.extend([item for sublist in [[x.real, x.imag] for x in answer] for item in sublist])
export[q-1] = line
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what we *do* use for exponentiation, `**`.